# Error al intentar agregar fila en datables.

Tags: jquery, datatables

Al intentar agregar una fila me lanza el siguiente error:

> DataTables warning: table id=table - Request unknown parameter 'nombre' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Este es el codigo del datatables

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var table = $('#table').DataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "tabla/cargos",
                "columns": [
                    {
                        sortable: false,
                        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                            return meta.row+1;
                        }
                    },
                    {data: 'nombre'},
                    {
                        sortable: false,
                        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                            return '<button class="edit-modal btn btn-info" data-id="'+full.id+'" data-nombre="'+full.nombre+'">'+
                                    '<span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Editar'+
                                   '</button> '+
                                   '<button class="delete-modal btn btn-danger" data-id="'+full.id+'" data-nombre="'+full.nombre+'">'+
                                    '<span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Eliminar'+
                                   '</button>'
                            ;
                        }
                    },
                ],
                "language": idioma_español
            });
            new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table );

            $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
                table.row.add( [
                    '10',
                    'Prueba',
                    'Botones'
                ] ).draw( false );
            } );

            // Automatically add a first row of data
            $('#addRow').click();
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> El error te esta avisando que no has indicado la propiedad `nombre` en el registro que intentas agregar.

Por lo que puedo ver `tabla/cargos` devuelve un arreglo de objetos con las propiedades `id` y `nombre`.

Con esta info se me ocurre que una solución podría ser la siguiente:

```
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
  table.row.add({
   id: '10',
   nombre: 'Prueba',
   algo: 'Botones' // No sabria decir a que prop responde este valor.
  });
});
```

Comment: la primera columna es un contador que le hice y el tercero son botones (como claramente lo dices). No se como indicarle esos. Bueno la unica solucion que encontre fue recargar la tabla cada vez que agregue un dato nuevo en la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía el mismo problema y encontre la solución de colocar los nombres de las columnas. Con eso se corrigió.

```
{
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bInfo": false,
            "autoWidth": false,  
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "sAjaxSource": "data.js",
            "columns": [
            { "data": "CustomerName" },
            { "data": "product" },
            { "data": "perticulars" },
            { "data": "AddressOfCustomer" },
            { "data": "ContactNumbers" }
        ]
        }
```

Lo encontré en [DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 1, column 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531975/datatables-warning-table-id-example-requested-unknown-parameter-1-for-row-1)